# Cross-site scripting validation for VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xss

Why I am getting cross-site scripting?

```vb
document.getElementById('<%= (HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txt.sampleID)) %>').disabled = true
```

Comment: why are doing `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`??

Comment: it will encode my client ID but its notworking

Comment: asp.net will not add any html characters to your ClientID while generating it. You may use the `document.getElementById` function without encoding.

Comment: I have done that its detecting as XSS vulnerability

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why is it still showing as XSS vulnerability but you could also sanitize ClientID, like for example if its a number just cast it to an integer.